# Por qué no puedo referenciar "this" dentro de un método de firebase en immnonic v2

Tags: array, ionic, typescript

Quiero agregar dinámicamente botones a mi ion-list desde el typescript leyendo de mi base de datos en firebase.

Éste es mi código:

```
export class AboutPage {

valor:any;
username:any;
to:any;
public items: Array<any> = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public translateService: 
TranslateService,  private ShareService: ShareService) {
 var app = ShareService.getApp();
 var database = app.database();
 var msj={};
 auth = app.auth();
 storage = app.storage();
 databaseRef = database.ref().child("chat");
 msgRef = database.ref().child("messages");
 storageRef = storage.ref().child('chat_photos');
 this.items = [{to:"michael"}];
 databaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

        var touser=snapshot.child("to").val();
        msj = {to:touser}
        //this.items.push(msj);

});
```

Agregué un caso donde agrega al array a `{to:michael}` y funciona correctamente, sin embargo cuando intento hacer la llamada dentro de la función de firebase (`this.items.push(msj)`), me da un error que dice que no se puede acceder a la propiedad items de null.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

Answer (score 3):

Para futuros lectores, en Typescript, si quieres escribir una función anónima que utilice la instancia del objecto (this) donde la función está declarada, lo mejor es utilizar una "función flecha" (arrow function).

En la pregunta en cuestión, la función anónima quedaría así:

```
(snapshot) => {
        var touser=snapshot.child("to").val();
        msj = {to:touser}
        this.items.push(msj);
}
```

Una función anónima "tradicional" `function(algo){ código }` no tiene acceso al objecto actual, habria que crear una variable local `var _this = this;` antes de la declaración de la función y utilizar esa variable dentro de la función, de esto precisamente es de lo que se encarga una función flecha por detrás del telón.